# "Scale in thirds" vs "scales a third apart" - what is the difference?

Tags: piano, scales, abrsm

I was just browsing through ABRSM syllabus and found two different things, as mentioned in the title.

What is the difference?

The syllabus is here: https://in.abrsm.org/fileadmin/user_upload/PDFs/Piano_Syllabus_2019___2020_complete.pdf. And the page number is 27.

Comment: Apologies for "under-specification" :-). The syllabus is here https://in.abrsm.org/fileadmin/user_upload/PDFs/Piano_Syllabus_2019___2020_complete.pdf. And the page number is 27.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess:

Regarding  the piano

*scale-in-thirds*

will mean thirds played with one hand

*scales-a-third-apart*

played with both hands.

Comment: Makes you wonder: in the syllabus why not simply write "scale in thirds in one hand" and "scales in each hand a third apart?"

Answer (score 0):

In addition to other ways of separating the two, I've also heard guitarists playing scales in thirds, playing (C-E-D-F-E-G-F-A... one after the other). They seem to call that playing the C major scale in thirds, but I'm not sure exactly how widespread that phrasing is.